# How can I get the JPA API version programmatically?

Tags: java, jpa, version

I am working on a spring boot project using JPA. Is there any class or method in that API which I can use to get a version string programmatically?

For example:

- for the hibernate version: `org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString()`
- for the thymeleaf version: `Thymeleaf.getVersion()`

Comment: From looking at the docs, I don't think so. Out of curiosity what do you need it for?

Comment: I want to save all software versions. If any bug/issue occors it can be helpful to know the exact version. Kind of sad that it doesn't seem possible...Spring and Springboot are better in that aspect.

Comment: Could you just use version control and look at your pom.xml or whatever the equivalent?

Comment: I am using version control. Just thought that it could be helpful printing all versions at startup or so. Guess "looking at the pom" is the way I will go now..